# How to test nginx errors?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to trigger an nginx error to test my error pages. This is what I tried:

```
server {
    // ...
    root /path/to/site
    error_page 504 502 500 = /html/error/500.html; # absolute path: /path/to/site/html/error/500.html
    return 500;
}
```

But I keep getting the default nginx error. Testing the html is not enough, I wanna make sure that nginx will show the correct error pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to add 404 Not found and try to access something Nginx couldn't resolve?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 server {
     root /path/to/site
     error_page 504 502 500 = /html/error/500.html;

     location /get_error {
         return 500;
     }
 }
```

See the docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html